# Optimizar y crear bucle sql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Hola buenas a todos soy nuevo en el foro y no se me da muy bien msql, necesitaría alguna ayuda por favor.

Me han dicho que tengo que optimizar esta consulta ya que siempre que se ejecuta el servidor se cae porque no da abasto. También me han que debo crear un bucle para ahorrar lineas.

En el bucle había pensando en un while para que se ejecute los 12 meses del año con un if para que cuando llegue al mes 12 se reinicie a 1. Ya que si ejecutamos la consulta en noviembre empezara por el mes 11, continuara por el mes 12 y tiene que pasar al mes 1, Pero siempre un total de 12 meses.

Esta seria la consulta sql:

Muchas gracias de antemano

```
SELECT clientes.codigo, clientes.denominacionFiscal,
 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes082019.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC082019',
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes082019.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP082019',

 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes092019.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC092019',
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes092019.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP092019',

 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes102019.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC102019',
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes102019.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP102019',

 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes112019.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC112019',
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes112019.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP112019',

 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes122019.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC122019',
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes122019.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP122019',

 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes012020.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC012020',
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes012020.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP012020',

 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes022020.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC022020',
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes022020.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP022020',

 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes032020.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC032020',
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes032020.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP032020',

 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes042020.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC042020',
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes042020.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP042020',

 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes052020.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC052020',
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes052020.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP052020',

 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes062020.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC062020',
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes062020.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP062020',
 (SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes072020.horaFacturables)))) AS 'FAC072020', 
(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mes072020.horaReportadas)))) AS 'REP072020', 

 usuarios.nombreCompleto AS nombreCompleto, clientes.localidad AS localidad, clientes.idprovincias AS provincia
FROM clientes
INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id= clientes.idConsultor
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 08 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019) mes082019 ON clientes.codigo = mes082019.cliente
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 09 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019) mes092019 ON clientes.codigo = mes082019.cliente
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 10 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019) mes102019 ON clientes.codigo = mes102019.cliente
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 11 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019) mes112019 ON clientes.codigo = mes112019.cliente
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 12 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019) mes122019 ON clientes.codigo = mes122019.cliente
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 01 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020) mes012020 ON clientes.codigo = mes012020.cliente
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 02 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020) mes022020 ON clientes.codigo = mes022020.cliente
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 03 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020) mes032020 ON clientes.codigo = mes032020.cliente
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 04 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020) mes042020 ON clientes.codigo = mes042020.cliente
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 05 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020) mes052020 ON clientes.codigo = mes052020.cliente
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 06 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020) mes062020 ON clientes.codigo = mes062020.cliente
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id_cust,customer.cliente,horaFacturables, horaReportadas
FROM customer
WHERE gender in (1,2) AND MONTH(fecha) = 07 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020) mes072020 ON clientes.codigo = mes072020.cliente
WHERE clientes.estatus='Alta'
GROUP BY clientes.codigo
```

Comment: Estas haciendo una tabla pivotante, de una suma de tiempos de datos agrupados por fechas... tu soucion es hacer primero una agrupacion por fecha, y luego generar las columnas que queres....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a ampliar un poco más, el comentario de Gonzalo. El problema que tienes, aún sin tener datos de los índices o los "query plan" del servidor, se puede llegar a saber por como tienes construida la consulta. Lo que se ve son 12 consultas a la tabla `customer` dónde, además, por las columnas, me imagino no tienen índices, por lo que hay una alta probabilidad que el motor esté haciendo un escaneo completo de la tabla, en este caso 12 veces. Como regla de trabajo, si tenemos que hacer un escaneo completo de una tabla, hagámoslo una sola vez. Por lo que la solución que podría proponerte es resolver en primer lugar los acumulados por clientes, con un `GROUP BY` y un `SUM` condicional. Algo así:

```
SELECT cliente,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 08 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC082019, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 08 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP082019,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 09 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC092019, 
       SUMTIME_TO_SEC((CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 09 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP092019
       FROM customer
       WHERE gender in (1,2)
       GROUP BY cliente
```

Lo armé solo para los dos primeros meses, para no hacer tan larga la respuesta, te tocá a tí agregar lo meses que faltan. Espero que se entienda la idea: agrupamos los clientes y hacemos 24 sumarizaciones que estarán condicionadas al mes y año. Como puedes ver, con esto resolvimos el problema de fondo haciendo una sola consulta a `customer`

Luego simplemente deberemos integrar esta consulta a la consulta anterior:

```
SELECT C.codigo, 
       C.denominacionFiscal,
       SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC082019) AS 'FAC082019',
       SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP082019) AS 'REP082019',
       SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC092019) AS 'FAC092019',
       SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP092019) AS 'REP092019'
       FROM clientes C
       INNER JOIN usuarios U
             ON U.id= C.idConsultor
       LEFT JOIN (

             <Aquí va la consulta anterior>

       ) T
              ON C.codigo = T.cliente
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto, con lo cual problema resuelto, se ha reducido mucho el tiempo de la consulta. Ahora tengo que hacer lo mismo con otras consultas para reducir el tiempo general.